# Returning all columns while still ordering by MIN aggregate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let me start by saying I'm not a database guy, and I very much have no idea what I'm doing. I welcome any and all comments or suggestions for improvement, even if not directly related to the question.

Anyways, I've got two tables, Events and Occurrences. Pretty typical setup: Occurrences has a foreign key to Events.Id, creating a one-to-many relationship. Occurrences have a StartDate and EndDate (both full datetime values, despite the name). So what I want to do is select all columns for all Events where there's at least one related row in Occurrences with either a future value for StartDate (hasn't started) or a future value for EndDate (started, but hasn't ended).

I've got the following query that works well from what I can tell (There's some logic in here for getting "live" events, published and not expired, etc. Pretty straight-forward stuff):

```
DECLARE @PublishedStatus INT = 2
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Events] e
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Occurrences] o
ON e.Id = o.EventId
    AND (o.StartDate > GETUTCDATE() OR o.EndDate > GETUTCDATE())
WHERE e.Status = @PublishedStatus
    AND e.PublishDate IS NOT NULL
    AND e.PublishDate <= GETUTCDATE()
    AND (e.ExpireDate IS NULL OR e.ExpireDate > GETUTCDATE())
```

The problem is that I now want to order this by the minimum StartDate value in the selected rows of Occurrences. If I try to add:

```
ORDER BY MIN(o.StartDate)
```

It won't work without also adding:

```
GROUP BY e.Id
```

Which then of course requires changing my select to

```
SELECT e.Id
```

Now, the problem is that I need all the columns from Events, not just the Id. I know this is how GROUP BY works, so it wasn't really a surprise. I'm just trying to find a middle ground, where I can somehow do both simultaneously. Unfortunately, as I said at the start, I'm not a pro at this, and I've reached the limit of my current abilities here.

Also, for what it's worth, this will be the basis for a stored procedure. It's going into an ORM, so I need all the columns back to properly instantiate the classes that represent this table. I'd prefer not to explicitly specify all the column names, as I would then need to always sync this stored procedure with any updates made to the schema of the table, if any should occur (additional columns added, etc.), but if that's the only way to achieve what I need, I'll deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY MIN(o.StartDate) means you want to order by StartDate with asending order.Right ?
So in that case you just add Order By StartDate Like :-

```
DECLARE @PublishedStatus INT = 2
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Events] e
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Occurrences] o
 ON e.Id = o.EventId
AND (o.StartDate > GETUTCDATE() OR o.EndDate > GETUTCDATE())
WHERE e.Status = @PublishedStatus
AND e.PublishDate IS NOT NULL
AND e.PublishDate <= GETUTCDATE()
AND (e.ExpireDate IS NULL OR e.ExpireDate > GETUTCDATE())
Order By o.StartDate ASC
```

Comment: (bangs head against keyboard) I guess I was just too close to it. It never occurred to be that I didn't need to order by the minimum StartDate, just StartDate in general. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly (which I'm not sure of) you can try something like this

```
DECLARE @PublishedStatus INT = 2

SELECT e.*
  FROM
(
    SELECT e.Id, MIN(o.StartDate) MinStartDate
      FROM [dbo].[Events] e INNER JOIN [dbo].[Occurrences] o
        ON e.Id = o.EventId
       AND (o.StartDate > GETUTCDATE() OR o.EndDate > GETUTCDATE())
     WHERE e.Status = @PublishedStatus
       AND e.PublishDate IS NOT NULL
       AND e.PublishDate <= GETUTCDATE()
       AND (e.ExpireDate IS NULL OR e.ExpireDate > GETUTCDATE())
      GROUP BY e.Id
 ) q JOIN [dbo].[Events] e 
   ON q.Id = e.Id
 ORDER BY MinStartDate
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but since I didn't actually need to sort by the minimum StartDate at all, I have to give it to Pragnesh.